# How to show the VPN password in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: network-manager, password, vpn

I followed this procedure for my Ubuntu 18.10 laptop

1. In the upper right corner of the desktop click on *VPN Settings*.
2. Click on the "wheel" symbol for my previously configured VPN.
3. Click on the tab *Identity*.

A password field with only stars is shown.

(I have previously configured the password with the option *Store the password only for this user*)

I would have expected to see a GUI icon with the text *Show password*
or something similar.
How can I show the VPN password that I have configured before?

Comment: This works on Linux Mint (Mate) too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. In a terminal type `seahorse`.
2. Click on the pad lock icon (A window is now shown with the title
   *Enter password to unlock your login keyring*)
3. In the password field type your password.
4. Click *Unlock*
5. Go to the menu *View* and select *View any*
6. In the list of passwords click on the entry *VPN password secret for ...*

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer -- thanks for the help!

Comment: I could not find it using these steps on Ubuntu 20.04